# How can I speed up powershell to get firewall rules on windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, optimization, firewall

I need to enumerate all firewall rules on windows 10 using PowerShell. I switched to PowerShell from `netsh` because some built-in rules were getting *funny* names like `@{microsoft.windows.shellexperiencehost_10.0.17134.1_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://microsoft.windows.shellexperiencehost/resources/pkgdisplayname}` which I was unable to manage with `netsh`. Switching to PowerShell shows that the real name was a UID and fixed my problem but the code is *really* slow to run:

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant\Desktop> Measure-Command {.\ps-slow.ps1 show}
Seconds           : 48
...
```

In contrast to `Measure-Command {show-netfirewallrule}`:

```
...
Milliseconds      : 644
```

And `netsh`:

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant\Desktop> Measure-Command { netsh advfirewall firewall show rule all verbose}
...
TotalSeconds      : 1.0588127
```

By commenting out the `Get-NetFirewall*Filter` part of the script it runs at full speed but of course is missing all the data I want. The idea is to collect detailed info on all firewall rules and then output the lot as JSON.

Does anyone have an idea how to optimize this? I'm a PowerShell noob so I'm hoping I missed something obvious. The complete script is:

```
Show-NetFirewallRule | `
    Where-Object { $_.cimclass.toString() -eq "root/standardcimv2:MSFT_NetFirewallRule" } | `
        ForEach-Object { `
            $af = $_ | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter | Select-Object -First 1; # Assumes only one filter
            $appf = $_ | Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter | Select-Object -First 1; # Assumes only one filter
            $pf = $_ | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Select-Object -First 1; # Assumes only one filter
            $if = $_ | Get-NetFirewallInterfaceTypeFilter | Select-Object -First 1; # Assumes only one filter

            New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
              Name = $_.Name
              DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
              Description = $_.Description
              Enabled = $_.Enabled.toString()
              Action = $_.Action.toString()
              Direction = $_.Direction.toString()
              EdgeTraversalPolicy = $_.EdgeTraversalPolicy.toString()
              Profile = $_.Profile.toString()
              DisplayGroup = $_.DisplayGroup
              # Address Filter
              LocalAddress = $af.LocalAddress
              RemoteAddress = $af.RemoteAddress
              LocalIp = $af.LocalIp
              RemoteIp = $af.RemoteIp
              # Port Filter
              LocalPort = $pf.LocalPort
              RemotePort = $pf.RemotePort
              Protocol = $pf.Protocol
              IcmpType = $pf.IcmpType
              # Application Filter
              Program = $appf.Program
              # Interface Filter
              InterfaceType = $if.InterfaceType.toString()
            }
        } | Convertto-json
```

Comment: i don't have access to that cmdlet - i'm on win7ps5.1 - but you are sending things across the pipeline MANY times. that is known to be slow. try changing the pipe to `Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter` so that it calls the object _directly_ via a parameter. then, since you only want the 1st of those objects, use array indexing to get item #1. ///// next is the `New-Item` call to make a custom object. that can be SLOW. use the type accelerator `[PSCustomObject]@{}` on its own to speed that call up a tad. ///// as an aside, why are you using backticks? those are at natural line continuations.

Comment: I tried rewriting to `$af = (Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter -AssociatedNetFirewallRule $_)[0]` but now it's even slower. Your right about the backticks, they're not needed. I wonder if I have this query _backwards_? The individual filter commands seem to work quickly maybe I should run those and somehow work backwards to the parent rule?

Comment: arg! i don't have any experience with those cmdlets, so i am at a loss for any more ideas. i'll go back to lurking ... [*grin*]

Comment: hey all good I appreciate your guesswork ;-) I can output all of the filters into arrays in less then a second but then I'm stumped at how to map them back to rules... argh!

Comment: You are asking for more than just the rule. If you what just get the rules quickly, then this works. Measure-Command {Get-NetFirewallRule | Where { $_.Enabled –eq ‘True’ –and $_.Direction –eq ‘Inbound’ } | Select-Object -Property * } which takes about 1.2 seconds on average. Now, because you are calling for additional logic checks, you should expect a slower response as each has to be processed before a response can be seen.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is faster, so, maybe a different approach for you to get the same information.

```
param
( 
    [switch]$Local, 
    [switch]$GPO 
) 

# If no switches are set the script will default to local firewall rules 
if (!($Local) -and !($Gpo)) 
{ $Local = $true } 

$RegistryKeys = @() 

if ($Local) {$RegistryKeys += 'Registry::HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules'} 
if ($GPO) {$RegistryKeys += 'Registry::HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\FirewallRules'} 

Foreach ($Key in $RegistryKeys) 
{ 
    if (Test-Path -Path $Key) 
    { 
        (Get-ItemProperty -Path $Key).PSObject.Members | 
        Where-Object {
        (@('PSPath','PSParentPath','PSChildName') -notcontains $_.Name) -and 
        ($_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty') -and 
        ($_.TypeNameOfValue -eq 'System.String')} | 
         ForEach-Object { 

            # Prepare hashtable 
            $HashProps = @{ 
                NameOfRule = $_.Name 
                RuleVersion = ($_.Value -split '\|')[0] 
                Action = $null 
                Active = $null 
                Dir = $null 
                Protocol = $null 
                LPort = $null 
                App = $null 
                Name = $null 
                Desc = $null 
                EmbedCtxt = $null 
                Profile = $null 
                RA4 = $null 
                RA6 = $null 
                Svc = $null 
                RPort = $null 
                ICMP6 = $null 
                Edge = $null 
                LA4 = $null 
                LA6 = $null 
                ICMP4 = $null 
                LPort2_10 = $null 
                RPort2_10 = $null 
            } 

            # Determine if this is a local or a group policy rule and display this in the hashtable 
            if ($Key -match 'HKLM\\System\\CurrentControlSet') 
            {  $HashProps.RuleType = 'Local' } 
            else 
            {  $HashProps.RuleType = 'GPO' } 

            # Iterate through the value of the registry key and fill PSObject with the relevant data 
            ForEach ($FireWallRule in ($_.Value -split '\|')) 
            { 
                switch (($FireWallRule -split '=')[0]) 
                { 
                    'Action' {$HashProps.Action = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'Active' {$HashProps.Active = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'Dir' {$HashProps.Dir = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'Protocol' {$HashProps.Protocol = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'LPort' {$HashProps.LPort = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'App' {$HashProps.App = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'Name' {$HashProps.Name = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'Desc' {$HashProps.Desc = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'EmbedCtxt' {$HashProps.EmbedCtxt = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'Profile' {$HashProps.Profile = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'RA4' {[array]$HashProps.RA4 += ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'RA6' {[array]$HashProps.RA6 += ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'Svc' {$HashProps.Svc = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'RPort' {$HashProps.RPort = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'ICMP6' {$HashProps.ICMP6 = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'Edge' {$HashProps.Edge = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'LA4' {[array]$HashProps.LA4 += ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'LA6' {[array]$HashProps.LA6 += ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'ICMP4' {$HashProps.ICMP4 = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'LPort2_10' {$HashProps.LPort2_10 = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    'RPort2_10' {$HashProps.RPort2_10 = ($FireWallRule -split '=')[1]} 
                    Default {} 
                } 
            } 

            # Create and output object using the properties defined in the hashtable 
            New-Object -TypeName 'PSCustomObject' -Property $HashProps
        } 
    } 
}

# Partial results

Action      : Allow
LPort2_10   : 
RuleType    : Local
LPort       : 135
Edge        : 
LA6         : 
Dir         : In
Desc        : @icsvc.dll,-710
ICMP4       : 
RA4         : 
Name        : @icsvc.dll,-709
LA4         : 
App         : %SystemRoot%\system32\svchost.exe
ICMP6       : 
Protocol    : 6
RuleVersion : v2.0
NameOfRule  : vm-monitoring-dcom
RPort       : 
Svc         : RpcSs
RA6         : 
Profile     : 
EmbedCtxt   : @icsvc.dll,-700
RPort2_10   : 
Active      : FALSE
```

Comment: hey thanks this is on the right track I think - my colleagues did some testing batching things up with the previous code and things got slower suggesting a WMI bottleneck and leaving best option as parsing the registry - this is great!

Comment: docs on what the keys mean: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff719844.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: No worries. If this works out for you as the usable answer, be sure to make it as such for others information.

Comment: Registry drilling is the way to go, it would be awesome to create a whole module for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks heaps for everyone who posted. The original problem was that `netsh` leaves unresolved names like:

```
@{Microsoft.Todos_1.41.12842.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.Todos/Resources/app_name_ms_todo}
@{Microsoft.Todos_1.41.12842.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.Todos/Resources/app_name_ms_todo}
```

In its output that can only be resolved by PowerShell, using the original script. The problem with this approach is that this is very slow (minutes).

Suggestions on this thread and from colleagues were:

- Use PS batching (made things slower - suggesting WMI bottleneck)
- Read the registry directly (mostly works, but data is left unresolved in different ways and would require slow registry scans to resolve - eg `@FirewallAPI.dll,-25427` to whatever resource that references)
- Use the COM API `New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy` (has the same output problems as `netsh`)
- Adjust use of pipelines/object creation (no measurable impact)

In summary, the optimization I want is impossible without sacrificing the data that I want. I'm going to attempt to use the faster COM API/netsh *most* of the time but switch to using the powershell API when there is no choice (when unresolved names force us to)

Answer (score 0):

Does `Get-NetFirewallRule` give you what you want?

```
$MyRules = Get-NetFirewallRule
foreach ($rule in $MyRules) {
    [the rest of your code]
}
```

Comment: no - I also need the filter information and its gathering this that is slow

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is well understood, but the get-netfirewall*filter commands are meant to do things faster.  Just compare the first pipeline to the second pipeline.  It's like using the -filter option in other commands like get-childitem or get-wmiobject.  I don't think even the writers of the online help understand this.  It's like powershell is only 80% documented.

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | 
Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | 
Where LocalPort -eq 3389 | Get-NetFirewallRule | 
Set-NetFirewallRule -RemoteAddress 192.168.1.1 -WhatIf
```

```
Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | 
Where LocalPort -eq 3389 | Get-NetFirewallRule | 
Set-NetFirewallRule -RemoteAddress 192.168.1.1 -WhatIf
```